Why specify a tensor only depends on its inputs at a point and not in a neighborhood of a point
I'm reading through Wald's general relativity book, and in it he specifies that an object (which turns out to be a tensor) only depends on its inputs at a point $p$. I can add in the details of the object he's talking about (difference of "derivative operators"), but I don't think it's important my question. Which is: why does he, and others, specifically say that the object only depends on it's inputs at a point, and not in a neighborhood of the point? Is this because a tensor, as he defines, is a multilinear map $V_p^* \times \cdots V_p^* \times V_p \times \cdots \times V_p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and so it's inputs (dual vectors and vectors) are coming from the vector spaces defined at $p$?
Sorry if this is confusing. I don't really know how to better ask this question.

When you study physics, you assume that the laws of physics are independent of units used in physical measurements. In geometry and general relativity, you assume that the geometric properties of space are independent of the coordinates used. Tensor analysis originated from these basic principles. When you try to extract coordinate-independent non-scalar (e.g., vector or matrix) things  from formulas written in coordinates, you discover that the most important ones satisfy the properties of what we now call tensors.

Have a look at "tangent spaces".
